# Can you style individual segments of a Path?

Tags: wpf, xaml, graphics, polyline

I'm showing a series of data points where the first segment in the series is colored differently than all the other segments (image 1).

At the moment the first segment is a separate object than the other segments in the series, which are all a single `Path` comprised by `PolyLineSegment`s.

You can see in the images that the mating surfaces between the first segment and the second (where the color changes) is not very clean, however it is rendered much nicer in the remaining cases (third image example).

Is it possible to alter the colors for individual segments? If so I could merge the standalone line into the `PathSegmentCollection` and I think that would resolve the rendering issue. But the various attributes such as `Stroke` are only available on the `Path` tag, not the subsidiary objects.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    <Line
        X1="{Binding LeadingCoordinate.Screen.X}"
        Y1="{Binding LeadingCoordinate.Screen.Y}"
        X2="{Binding Coordinates[0].Screen.X}"
        Y2="{Binding Coordinates[0].Screen.Y}"
        Stroke="Red"
        StrokeThickness="5"
        Opacity="0.25"
        StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
        StrokeEndLineCap="Flat"
        />

    <Path
        Stroke="Blue"
        StrokeThickness="5"
        Opacity="0.25"
        StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
        StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
        StrokeLineJoin="Round"
        >
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding ScreenPoints[0]}">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <PolyLineSegment Points="{Binding ScreenPoints}"/>
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Comment: You have answered the question yourself: "*the various attributes such as Stroke are only available on the Path*".

Comment: @Clemens I was afraid there was no way around that :(  Often WPF has either some arcane workaround or just an alternative approach that is suitable. Thanks